# Is a scan query always expensive in DynamoDB or should you use a range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I've been playing around with Amazon DynamoDB and looking through their examples but I think I'm still slightly confused by the example. I've created the example data on a local dynamodb instance to get used to querying data etc. The sample data sets up 3 tables of 'Forum'->'Thread'->'Reply'

Now if I'm in a specific forum, the thread table has a ForumName key I can query against to return relevant threads, but would the very top level (displaying the forums) always have to be a scan operation?

From what I can gather the only way to "select *" in dynamodb is to use a scan and I assume in this instance - where forum is very high level and might have a relatively small number of rows - that it wouldn't be that *expensive* or are you actually better creating a hash and range key and using that to query this table? I'm not sure what the range key would be in this instance, maybe just a number and then specify in the query that the value has to be > 0? Or perhaps a date it was created and the query always uses a constant date in the past?

I did try a sample query on the 'Forum' table example data using a ComparisonOperator of 'GE' (Greater than or equal) with an attribute value list of 'S'=>'a' but this states that any conditions on the hash key must be of type EQ which implies I couldn't do the above as I would always need to know my 'Name' values upfront

Maybe I'm still struggling having come from an RDBS background especially seen as there are many forum examples out there.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think using Scan to get all the forums is fine. I think it is very efficient because it will not return you anything that you don't need (all of the work that scan does is necessary). Also since Scan operation is so simple it is easier to implement and more likely to be efficient